# How to use Synthetica Addons

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I download the [SyntheticaAddons](http://www.jyloo.com/syntheticaaddons/) and themes from the official website; but once I use it in my NetBeans project, it ends up with an exception.

I need to use specially `JYTable`, but I fail several times. Can anyone help me regarding this matter?

```
package controller;

import de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaBlueLightLookAndFeel;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import de.javasoft.swing.JYTable;
import de.javasoft.swing.JYTableHeader;
import de.javasoft.swing.JYTableScrollPane;
import de.javasoft.swing.jytable.renderer.CellLayoutHint;

/**
  * Demonstrates how to use a JYTable.
 */
 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
 public class SimpleJYTable extends JFrame
 {
  public SimpleJYTable()
  {
super("Simple JYTable");
createAndAddComponents(getContentPane());

//setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);      
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
setSize(700,300);
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
setVisible(true);
 }

 /**
  * Create components and add them to the container.
  */
 private void createAndAddComponents(Container container)
  {
String[] columnNames = {"First Name", "Last Name", "Sport", "# of Years", "Vegetarian"};
Object[][] data = { 
                    {"Kathy", "Smith", "Snowboarding", 5, false},
                    {"John", "Doe", "Rowing", 3, true}, 
                    {"Sue", "Black", "Knitting", 2, false},
                    {"Jane", "White", "Speed reading", 20, true}, 
                    {"Joe", "Brown", "Pool", 10, false}
                  };
final Class<?>[] columnClasses = {String.class, String.class, String.class,
                                                        Integer.class,Boolean.class}; 

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames)
{
  @Override
  public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex)
  {
    return columnClasses[columnIndex];
  }
};
JYTable table = new JYTable(model);
JYTableHeader header =  (JYTableHeader)table.getTableHeader();
CellLayoutHint hint = header.getCellLayoutHint();
//center header text
header.setCellLayoutHint(new CellLayoutHint(hint.sortMarkerPosition, SwingConstants.CENTER, 
                                                                       hint.verticalAlignment));
//use a JYTableScrollPane for the filter row
JYTableScrollPane scrollPane = new JYTableScrollPane(table);
container.add(scrollPane);    
}


 /**
 * Static main method for application startup. 
  */
 public static void main(String[] args)
{
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
  public void run()
  {
    try
    {
      UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SyntheticaBlueLightLookAndFeel());
      new SimpleJYTable();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  });
 }

 }
```

This will end up with following exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TO_STRING_UI
at  de.javasoft.swing.jytable.renderer.TableHeaderCellProvider.setStringValue
                                                                (TableHeaderCellProvider.java:58)
at org.jdesktop.swingx.renderer.ComponentProvider.<init>(ComponentProvider.java:158)
at org.jdesktop.swingx.renderer.ComponentProvider.<init>(ComponentProvider.java:133)
at de.javasoft.swing.jytable.renderer.TableHeaderCellProvider.<init>
                                                             (TableHeaderCellProvider.java:27)
at  de.javasoft.swing.jytable.renderer.DefaultTableHeaderRenderer.createDefaultComponentProvider
  (DefaultTableHeaderRenderer.java:136)
at org.jdesktop.swingx.renderer.AbstractRenderer.<init>(AbstractRenderer.java:40)
at de.javasoft.swing.jytable.renderer.DefaultTableHeaderRenderer.<init>
 (DefaultTableHeaderRenderer.java:71)
at de.javasoft.swing.jytable.renderer.DefaultTableHeaderRenderer.<init>
(DefaultTableHeaderRenderer.java:59)
at de.javasoft.swing.jytable.renderer.DefaultTableHeaderRenderer$DefaultTableHeaderRendererUI.
  <init>(DefaultTableHeaderRenderer.java:147)
at de.javasoft.swing.JYTableHeader.createDefaultRenderer(JYTableHeader.java:139)
```

So please help me?

Comment: This overly broad question also lacks sufficient detail to answer and appears to solicit recommendations for an alternative.

Comment: Actually I need to know how to use Synthetica Addons with java.

Comment: Please edit your question include a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and stack trace that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: I put the code and exception I got..Hope you will help me..

Comment: +1 for updates; withdrawing close vote; hopefully, someone who knows the library can address this.

Comment: Thanks..I hope some one come quickly to save me..:P

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem.Now it works fine after adding swingx-1.6.5

Comment: It worked for me. I was struggling with "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TO_STRING_UI" after executing jar created using IntelliJ IDEA !!

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA, [File] --> [Project Structure] --> [Libraries] --> [+] --> [Path to swingx-all-1.6.5]